# How to export a header before the data in the result file?

Tags: export, string-manipulation, data

I would like to export a phrase to my result data as a heading.

I'm exporting the data correctly with

```
 Export["file.dat", table].
```

But I'm doing several simulations with different parameters and I would like to write down this parameters in the file. I'm trying with

```
 Write["file.dat", {"Resonance simulation Data =", DateString[], "Parametros: Nz = ", Nz, " CP = ", CP, " K1 = ", K1}];
```

but this erases the precedent data if it's put after the `Export` or it is erased if it came before. How could I do this?

Comment: Take a look at `OpenAppend[file]`

Comment: Maybe `Import` the file, `Insert` the new line, and then `Export` the file again? For example, `Export["file.dat", Insert[Import["file.dat"], firstline, 1]]` where `firstline= {"Resonance simulation ...}`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following steps to prepend your headers:

1. import the file using `Import`
2. prepend your header using `Prepend`
3. Export the data using `Export`

   data = Import["file.dat"]

> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}

```
headers = {"param1","param2"};
data = Prepend[data,headers]
```

> {{"param1", "param2"}, {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}

```
Export["file.dat",data];
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `OpenAppend[]` and `Write[]` instead of `Export[]` to persist your data.

```
fn = "c:\\test.dat";
s = OpenWrite@fn;
Write[s, "**Header 1 **"];
Close[s];
s = OpenAppend@fn;
Write[s, Table[i, {i, 10}]];
Close[s];
s = OpenAppend@fn;
Write[s, "**Trailer 1 **"];
Close[s];
FilePrint[fn]
```

> "**Header 1 **"
>   {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
>   "**Trailer 1 **"

Answer (score 3):

You can open a stream, write your header, and then pass the stream to Export:

```
width = 7;
height = 4;
max = 6;
table = RandomInteger[{1, max}, {width}];
st = OpenWrite["file.dat"] ; Write["file.dat", {DateString[], 
  "width = ", width, " height = ", height, " max = ", max}];
Export[st, table];
FilePrint["file.dat"]
```

Comment: Is that syntax (using a stream in Export[] and not a filename) documented somewhere?

Comment: I don't think it is documented, so this is a "use with caution" answer, as it may change in future versions.  Although I would like to see it documented and officially supported, because it makes Export that much more flexible, as here.

Comment: Fully agree. Thanks!

Comment: Great to know! Thanks